# XML-schema: Equivalent to nullable="true" for attributes?

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb

I have been having problem with adding type="date" in my schema, as whenever it is null it throws a marshalling error. I found out that for elements we can add an attribute like nullable="true" and get rid of this issue. But, wasn't able to  find similar way for attributes. Is there a way to avoid this issue for attributes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

don't know if this is what you need, but I had problem with empty date (in xml: date="") and I coped with it like that:

```
<xs:simpleType name="mydatetype">
  <xs:union>
 <xs:simpleType>
  <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
 <xs:simpleType>
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
   <xs:minLength value="0" />
   <xs:maxLength value="0" />
  </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:union>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no "nillable" option for attributes, unfortunately.

You can however adorn an attribute with a `use="optional"` specifier which should take care of the case where the attribute is not present (shouldn't cause an error).

Marc

Comment: Hi Marc, I am using use="optional" attribute, but it is not helping with this issue.

Comment: hhmm.... odd.... not sure if that's a quirk or problem in jaxb - I'm not familiar with that tool, so I can't really help there....